# Test the difference between two (genetic) correlations, when only standard errors and z-statistics are available

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

I have two correlations (genetic correlations actually), their standard errors, and their z-statistics (but I don't know the sample sizes). Is it possible to do a significance test for the difference between these (genetic) correlations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  The reason is because if you have $r$ and $SE_r$, you do indeed have the sample sizes:
$$SE_r = \sqrt{\frac{1-r}{n-2}}$$
or
$$n = \frac{1-r}{SE_r^2}+2$$

In your OP, you mention "z-statistics".  I believe you are referencing the Fisher's z-transformation (as if you were referring to a test statistic for the correlation, it would be a t-ratio). This is important, because the Fisher transform is needed for the hypothesis test to compare the two correlations:
$$H_0 : \rho_1 = \rho_2$$

To conduct the test, transform the correlations to Fisher z:
$$z_i = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{1+r_i}{1-r_i}\right)$$
Using the standard error for the differences:
$$s=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1-3} + \frac{1}{n_2-3}}$$
you can use the standard normal distribution to find the P-value for
$$\zeta = \frac{z_1-z_2}{s}$$
(This last value is just a z-score, but as we've used z for something else, I called it zeta instead.)